# Vault error: Correct the classpath of your application so contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration

Tags: spring-security, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault

I have been trying to resolve this problem for a while but could understand why all the suggested options didn't work. It is the problem of pom calling the wrong dependency. This is my POM file

```
<properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As suggested on some SO answers I ran `mvn dependency:tree` and found out that there are 2 dependencies it's calling. Excluding the other dependencies didn't change anything because it's still calling the same thing.

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-vault-config:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-vault-config:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.vault:spring-vault-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
```

What else can I do?

This is the error I[m still getting

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=65191:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/wikiwoo/IdeaProjects/inventoryservice/target/classes:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-amqp/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-amqp-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.4.5/spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.13.3/log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.13.3/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.30/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.27/snakeyaml-1.27.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging/5.3.6/spring-messaging-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.6/spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/amqp/spring-rabbit/2.3.6/spring-rabbit-2.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/amqp/spring-amqp/2.3.6/spring-amqp-2.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/5.10.0/amqp-client-5.10.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.3.6/spring-context-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.3.6/spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.6/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/3.4.5/HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.3.6/spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/1.3.3/jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.30.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.27.0-GA/javassist-3.27.0-GA.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.22/byte-buddy-1.10.22.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.2.3.Final/jandex-2.2.3.Final.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.3/dom4j-2.1.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.2.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.4/jaxb-runtime-2.3.4.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.4/txw2-2.3.4.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.12/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.4.8/spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.4.8/spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.3.6/spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.3.6/spring-aspects-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-hateoas/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-hateoas-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-web-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-json-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.11.4/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.4.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.11.4/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.11.4.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.45/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jakarta.el/3.0.3/jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.45/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.6/spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/hateoas/spring-hateoas/1.2.5/spring-hateoas-1.2.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/jakarta.mail/1.6.7/jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/5.4.6/spring-security-config-5.4.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.4.6/spring-security-core-5.4.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.3.6/spring-expression-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-oauth2-client/5.4.6/spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/8.36.1/oauth2-oidc-sdk-8.36.1.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/content-type/2.1/content-type-2.1.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/lang-tag/1.4.4/lang-tag-1.4.4.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-security-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.3.6/spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/5.4.6/spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-oauth2-jose/5.4.6/spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.4.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/8.20.2/nimbus-jose-jwt-8.20.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/github/stephenc/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0-1/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/2.3/json-smart-2.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/net/minidev/accessors-smart/1.2/accessors-smart-1.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.4/asm-5.0.4.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-oauth2-core/5.4.6/spring-security-oauth2-core-5.4.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.6/spring-core-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.3.6/spring-jcl-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp/3.0.2/spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit/3.1.2/spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit-3.1.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bus/3.0.2/spring-cloud-bus-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/5.4.6/spring-integration-core-5.4.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-core/3.4.5/reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.3/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-config-client/3.0.3/spring-cloud-config-client-3.0.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.4.5/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-commons/3.0.2/spring-cloud-commons-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/5.4.6/spring-security-crypto-5.4.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-context/3.0.2/spring-cloud-context-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.3.6/spring-web-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.4/jackson-annotations-2.11.4.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.4/jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.4/jackson-core-2.11.4.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.15/commons-codec-1.15.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-config/3.0.3/spring-cloud-starter-config-3.0.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter/3.0.2/spring-cloud-starter-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-rsa/1.0.9.RELEASE/spring-security-rsa-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.64/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.64.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.64/bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap/3.0.2/spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.4.5/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.4.5/spring-boot-actuator-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.11.4/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.4.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.6.6/micrometer-core-1.6.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.12/HdrHistogram-2.1.12.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/latencyutils/LatencyUtils/2.0.3/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client/3.0.2/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/3.0.2/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/netflix/eureka/eureka-client/1.10.11/eureka-client-1.10.11.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/netflix/netflix-commons/netflix-eventbus/0.3.0/netflix-eventbus-0.3.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/netflix/netflix-commons/netflix-infix/0.3.0/netflix-infix-0.3.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/commons-jxpath/commons-jxpath/1.3/commons-jxpath-1.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.4/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/antlr/stringtemplate/3.2.1/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math/2.2/commons-math-2.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.14/xstream-1.4.14.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/netflix/servo/servo-core/0.12.21/servo-core-0.12.21.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/guava-19.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.10/commons-configuration-1.10.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.1.0/guice-4.1.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.4.0/jettison-1.4.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/netflix/eureka/eureka-core/1.10.11/eureka-core-1.10.11.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/woodstox/woodstox-core/5.3.0/woodstox-core-5.3.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/4.2/stax2-api-4.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer/3.0.2/spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/3.0.2/spring-cloud-loadbalancer-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/addons/reactor-extra/3.4.3/reactor-extra-3.4.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-cache/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-cache-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/5.3.6/spring-context-support-5.3.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/stoyanr/evictor/1.0.0/evictor-1.0.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-vault-config/3.0.2/spring-cloud-starter-vault-config-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.14/httpcore-4.4.14.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-vault-config/3.0.2/spring-cloud-vault-config-3.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.3.0/spring-vault-core-2.3.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/3.1.2/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-3.1.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core/3.1.2/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core-3.1.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-amqp/5.4.6/spring-integration-amqp-5.4.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/http-client/2.1.0.RELEASE/http-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-stream/3.1.2/spring-cloud-stream-3.1.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.4.5/spring-boot-starter-validation-2.4.5.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.1.7.Final/hibernate-validator-6.1.7.Final.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/retry/spring-retry/1.3.1/spring-retry-1.3.1.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-function-context/3.1.2/spring-cloud-function-context-3.1.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/net/jodah/typetools/0.6.2/typetools-0.6.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-function-core/3.1.2/spring-cloud-function-core-3.1.2.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-jmx/5.4.6/spring-integration-jmx-5.4.6.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.2.19/postgresql-42.2.19.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.5.0/checker-qual-3.5.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.20/lombok-1.18.20.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.4.0/json-path-2.4.0.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar com.christdoes.microservice.inventoryservice.InventoryserviceApplication
2021-05-03 14:18:20.840  WARN 80494 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultPropertySourceLocator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapPropertySourceConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultPropertySourceLocator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration$ClientFactoryWrapper]: Factory method 'clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration.<init>(org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration, org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration, java.util.List, java.util.List)'
2021-05-03 14:18:20.876  INFO 80494 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-03 14:18:20.914 ERROR 80494 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfiguration.createSslConfiguration(VaultConfiguration.java:101)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration.<init>(org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration, org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration, java.util.List, java.util.List)'

The method's class, org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.3.0/spring-vault-core-2.3.0.jar!/org/springframework/vault/support/SslConfiguration.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration: file:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.3.0/spring-vault-core-2.3.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration

2021-05-03 14:18:20.916 ERROR 80494 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfiguration.createSslConfiguration(VaultConfiguration.java:101)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration.<init>(org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration, org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration, java.util.List, java.util.List)'

The method's class, org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.3.0/spring-vault-core-2.3.0.jar!/org/springframework/vault/support/SslConfiguration.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration: file:/Users/wikiwoo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.3.0/spring-vault-core-2.3.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please check this issue, the possible resolution is to change the version spring-vault to 2.3.2

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/584